# Contar valores de elementos de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte `array`, por exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 401675295
            [DATA] => 2016-06-28 15:33:07
            [TITULO] => Teste
            [TEXTO] => 
            [TIPO] => 4
            [NOME] => JOAO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 401675295
            [DATA] => 2016-06-28 16:34:31
            [TITULO] => Avaliação
            [TEXTO] => 
            [TIPO] => 3
            [NOME] => VITOR
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 401675295
            [DATA] => 2016-06-28 16:34:41
            [TITULO] => Atendimento
            [TEXTO] => 
            [TIPO] => 3
            [NOME] => JOAO
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 401675295
            [DATA] => 2016-06-28 16:34:52
            [TITULO] => Concluido
            [TEXTO] =>
            [TIPO] => 1
            [NOME] => PAULO
        )

)
```

Como consigo contar o **[TIPO]** por valor? Como saber quantos **[TIPO]** são iguais a 3, ou a 4 por exemplo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É bem simples. Use `array_map` para listar todos os elementos com nome `TIPO`. Depois, utilize a função `array_count_values` para saber o resultado.

```
$tipos = array_map(function ($value) { return $value['TIPO'];}, $array);

array_count_values($tipos);
```

Veja um exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/4gcUsw)

Comment: Não deu certo, mostrou  "Undefined index: TIPO"

Comment: Sim, esta $array = array(); e aquele array que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Valeu, consegui, tava errando um nome aqui. =P